# Why does forward-difference give a different value than backward-difference?

Tags: numerical-methods

We are given that for $x_0 = 0.5, x_1 = 0.6$ and $x_2 = 0.7$, we have $f(x_0) = 0.4794, f(x_1) = 0.5646$ and $f(x_2) = 0.6442$. Also $h = 1$.

The forward-difference formula is $f'(x) = \dfrac{f(x_i + h) - f(x_i)}{h}$ and the backward-difference formula is $f'(x) = \dfrac{f(x_i) - f(x_i - h)}{h}$ .

Now, using forward-difference for $f'(0.6)$, I get

$\displaystyle f'(0.6) = \frac{f(0.7) - f(0.6)}{0.1} =  \frac{0.6442 - 0.5646}{0.1} = 0.796$.

However, when using backward-difference for $f'(0.6)$, I get

$\displaystyle f'(0.6) = \frac{f(0.6) - f(0.5)}{0.1} =  \frac{0.5646 - 0.4794}{0.1} = 0.852$.

Clearly, $0.796$ and $0.852$ are not the same value.

So, what is the value for $f'(0.6)$?  The answer in the back of the textbook says that it is $0.852$.  Why is it $0.852$ and not $0.796$?

Comment: You are taking a linear approximation of the derivative, not calculating an actual derivative. Both answers are correct, as both are approximations of the derivative. You will find that the "forward-difference" and "backward-difference" are the same when a function is linear (that is not the only way it will be the same, but it is the only way the differences will *always* be the same for any choice of points and any $h$).

Comment: Thank you, now I understand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each is only an approximate derivative. The textbook happens to assume you use the backward derivative. While neither of these two options has an inherent advantage over the other, $(f(x+h)-f(x-h))/(2h)$ is typically much more accurate than either of them.

Comment: Thank you!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because in general $f(x_0)$ and $f(x_2)$ can take different values.